# Measure text in canvas with stroke - Android

Tags: android, user-interface, canvas, textview, bounds

I'm trying to make a custom textview and I'm struggling to measure my stroked text. I know that a text size can be easily determined using

```
 TEXT_PAINT.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
```

However, I have a paint that draws a stroke around the text.

```
    WHITE_BORDER_PAINT = new Paint();
    WHITE_BORDER_PAINT.setTypeface(font);
    WHITE_BORDER_PAINT.setTextSize(textSize);
    WHITE_BORDER_PAINT.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    WHITE_BORDER_PAINT.setStrokeWidth(bigBorderSize);
    WHITE_BORDER_PAINT.setColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
```

I'd like to know how to determine the bounds of that drawing, as `getTextBounds` is returning 0 for `WHITE_BORDER_PAINT`